# VS Code Pylint highlighting the whole function with blue underline on missing function/class docstring

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

This just suddenly started happening where python pylint will highlight the whole function with blue squiggly lines when for a missing function docstring warning. How can I get it to only highlight the function definition or make a small indicator on the definition line. Its super annoying to get the whole file highlighted when you're developing.

Here's an example of a missing class docstring. The whole file becomes ridiculous to work with.

example of annoying behavior

[image: example of annoying behavior]

Desired behaviour is just a small quiggle at the beginning of the line. Thats how it used to be.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io1gp.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution for this is being [actively](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5466) discussed and developed at the Pylint project. The workarounds until a fix is merged are either to use an earlier version of VS Code (before January 2022) or Pylint (below 2.12.2). If the latter is desired, you can download a local copy and specify a custom path to Pylint in the Python extension settings.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts!

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in pylint 2.13.0 ( https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.13/full.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-13-0 )

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @Jacob Walls, you can downgrade the pylint linter or switch to another linter such as flake8.

```
pip install pylint==2.12.1
```